Multiple Shape Key Driver
Im just new to drivers I figure out how to do it with bones but when it comes to multiple shape keys Im bit confused and need help.. For example I have 1 shape key that works with bone it makes skin close the finger but it is clipping so I need another shape key to fix first shape key. Problem is I don't know how to use it together with first shape key. I mean when I move bone first shape keys works but second one is so slow.. It has to be become 1 to 1000 value faster to work but I don't know how to do that.

You should post screenshots and/or upload a blendfile to help us understand your issue a bit more clearly.
